# Read data from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, key, appsettings

How is it possible to read dynamic data from web.config. This is what I have:

```
      <appSettings>
<add key="TemplatesRootPath" value="System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath('~\\PSDtemplates\\MasterTemplates\\')"/></appSettings>
```

When I try to get real value of the key *TemplatesRootPath*:

```
var result= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplatesRootPath"];
```

I am getting the string under the value tag "*System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath('~\PSDtemplates\MasterTemplates\)*" as a result.

I do not want that, I would like to get something like

```
C:\\Code\\MyProject\\Project.WEBAPI\\MasterTemplates\\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config is a XML file you can't use C# code like : System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment because that is not XML.

What you can do however is set "~\PSDtemplates\MasterTemplates\" as your value and then in your code you can say:

`string TemplatesRootPath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplatesRootPath"];
TemplatesRootPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\PSDtemplates\MasterTemplates\");`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!